# Convergence of delta function in $L^{\varepsilon + 1/2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

I am currenly reading a paper which states (but does not prove) that any sequence of delta functions converges to zero in $L^{\varepsilon + 1/2}$ for $\varepsilon < 1/2$. Is there a good reference for reading up on this or is the proof obvious?

Comment: What is $d$ in the title?

Comment: My bad. $d$ was suppose to be a 1! Edited.

Comment: What is $L^{\varepsilon + 1/2}$?